# how do I use the next line in the terminal?

Tags: python

how do I use the next line the the terminal on mac os,

for example when I'm using a for loop with many lines:

```
>>> for i in range(9)
>>>
```

when I use the enter button it executes the command and returns a styrax error.

I need it to be something like this:

```
>>> for i in range(9)
...
```

I searched about it but couldn't find the answer to it,                                        (I'm new to using the terminal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a colon.

```
>>> for i in range(9):
```